# How to pass data in react among different files or routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-component, react-state, reach-router

I'm new to react and after a beginners course of learning react. i decided to take a personal project of creating a monthly subscription app that'll help me keep track of all my subscriptions. However, i'm stuck at a point where i need to pass the state of one component into another but that other component is accessible through a route, btw i'm using reach router. is there any way that is possible. below is my code. So what i want to do basically is that when i click on of the subscriptions in my list, (say: Netflix) it should basically take me another page, and show me all the neccesary details regarding that subscription. Here i want state (mylist) to be passed.

**App.js**

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Router>
        <List path="/" />
        <Details path="/details/:sub" />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**List.js**

```js
const List = () => {
  const [mylist, setList] = React.useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState({
    subscription: "",
    startDate: "",
    paymentTime: 0,
  });

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    mylist.push(value);
    setList(mylist);
    setValue({ subscription: "", startDate: "", paymentTime: 0 });
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  const handleOnChange = (event) => {
    setValue({ ...value, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="for_list">
        <ul className="list">
          {mylist.map((obj) => (
            // <Link to={`/details/${obj.subscription}`} key={obj.subscription}>
            <li key={obj.subscription}>{obj.subscription}</li>
            /* </Link> */
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="for_form">
        <form>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="subscription"
            onChange={handleOnChange}
            value={value.subscription}
          />
          <input
            type="date"
            name="startDate"
            onChange={handleOnChange}
            value={value.startDate}
          />
          <input
            type="number"
            name="paymentTime"
            onChange={handleOnChange}
            value={value.paymentTime}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Add Item</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

**Details.js**

```js
const Details = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
       Dunno what to do ;(
    </div>
  );
};
export default Details;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Router uses `location` objects. One of the properties of a `location` object is `state`. You can pass some data field to state, then in your `Details` page, you will use these data fields to fetch data of each corresponding subscription.

In your `List.js`:

```js
...
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  mylist.push(value);
  setList(mylist);
  setValue({ subscription: "", startDate: "", paymentTime: 0 });
  props.histoty.push({
    pathname: '/details/netflix',
    state: {
      id: 'netflix-id',
    }
  })
};
...

export default withRouter(List);
```

Then in your `Details.js`:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const Details = (props) => {
  const [subInfo, setSubInfo] = useState({})
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`your-server-api/${props.state.id}`).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setSubInfo(data))
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
       ...
    </div>
  );
};
export default withRouter(Details);
```

One thing to keep in mind is that there will be no state if a user navigates directly to the page, so you will still need some mechanism to load the data when it does not exist.